# How to get access to Headless Flow Pilot access

Tags: workflow, flow

i have to use Headless flows in my developer org.How to apply for this Pilot feature. in How much time i get access to this feature Plz guideline.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, You'll need an old priest and a young priest.

Just kidding.

Typically to request access to a pilot program, you initiate the conversation with your Account Executive.

Lets say you work for Big Co., who's Salesforce Account Executive (AE) is named "Bob Finley". You'd email Bob something like:

Dear Bob,

Just wanted to write and tell you I love your work. Salesforce has had a tremendous positive impact here at Big co. and with the features we read about in the release notes it's only going to have a bigger and bigger impact.

One of those features we just read about is the Headless Flow feature. We were hoping to try and get access to this pilot program, so that we can develop some headless flows -- we're excited about this new technology and would greatly appreciate hearing back from you about how we can apply.

Thanks, and as always You're Awesome.
-User133421

Comment: I'd add you to the pilot if you were kissing up to me like that (and I had power).